# Creating a Config.php from Within PHP, unable to close all variables properly

Tags: php

Hoping this is a oversight. 
Please a INI is not a option, this is needed to be a Config.php because of the multiple Bash scripts that report data back from these files.

This is a self installer, and the one thing i am having issues with is the Config.php (Obviously, a INI would be miles easier if it was an option)

We have a build up set of Variables am passing to an array to write into the file. 
The problem is happening here:

```
$data7 = '$databasename = "user'.$ClientID.";" ;
$data8 = '$databaseusername = "user'.$ClientID.";" ;
```

The Output of this is:

```
 $databasename = "user999;
 $databaseusername = "user999;
```

As you can see i am unable to pass along the last " without a Syntax problem from the installer.

ClientID and a good few other options are passed across from POST (HTML Form). (Its all consistency data)
Database users and passwords etc is all created else where and file appended at the bottom with the password (For security, as i know a few of you will touch on this point)
Any advise or a work around?

Comment: Well, escape them. Or why didn't you include them in single quotes → like you already did in the preceding string..?

Comment: Further reading: `var_export` and using arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be

```
$data7 = '$databasename = "user' . $ClientID . '";';
$data8 = '$databaseusername = "user' . $ClientID . '";';
```

Comment: Thank you! Too many singles and doubles i was getting lost! 
i forgot the last wrap of singles.

Answer (score 0):

```
$data7 = '$databasename = "user'.$ClientID.'";' ;
```

or

```
$data8 = '$databaseusername = "user'.$ClientID."\";" ;
```

Comment: Although this might solve the problem, you should also include a description explaining why and how this helps.